# Правильно ли я понял ООП в прототипном стиле?

Tags: javascript

Изучил ООП в прототипном стиле, но для гарантии правильности полученных знаний, хотел поинтересоваться, все ли я верно понял?

Ниже набросал конструктор с методами и свойствами, постарался изобразить большинство базовых операций внутри конструктора.

Дополнительный вопрос: в функциональном стиле можно ограничить доступ к приватным свойствам/методам. Изучая прототипный стиль, замечаю, что пишут приватные свойства/методы через первое подчеркивание, например: `_namePropertyPrivate` или `_nameMethodPrivate` - это такого рода реализация приватных свойств/методов?

```
// конструктор 1
function Construct() {
    this._privateProperty = 'Я приватное свойство Construct';
    this.publicProperty = 'Я публичное свойство Construct';
}

// приватные методы
Construct.prototype._privateMethod1 = function() {
    return `Я приватный метод -> ${this.publicProperty}`;
}

Construct.prototype._privateMethod2 = function() {
    return `Я приватный метод -> ${this._privateProperty}`;
}

// публичные методы
Construct.prototype.publicMethod1 = function() {
    return 'Я публичный метод Construct';
}

Construct.prototype.publicMethod2 = function() {
    return this._privateMethod1();
}

Construct.prototype.publicMethod3 = function() {
    return this._privateMethod2();
}

let construct = new Construct();

// обращаемся к приватному свойству
console.log(construct._privateProperty); // 'Я приватное свойство Construct'

// обращаемся к публичному свойству
console.log(construct.publicProperty); // 'Я публичное свойство Construct'

// обращаемся к приватному методу
console.log(construct._privateMethod1()); // 'Я приватный метод Construct'

// обращаемся к публичному методу
console.log(construct.publicMethod1()); // 'Я публичный метод Construct'

// обращаемся к публичному методу -> к публичному свойству
console.log(construct.publicMethod2()); // 'Я приватный метод -> Я публичное свойство Construct'

// обращаемся к публичному методу -> к приватному свойству
console.log(construct.publicMethod3()); // 'Я приватный метод -> Я приватное свойство Construct'

// конструктор 2
function Construct2() {}

// наследование
Construct2.prototype = Object.create(Construct.prototype);
Construct2.prototype.constructor = Construct2;

// объявляем новый конструктор
let construct2 = new Construct2();

Construct2.prototype.publicMethod4 = function() {
    return `${construct.publicProperty} вызванное из Construct2`;
}

// унаследовали
console.log(construct2.publicMethod4()); // 'Я публичное свойство Construct вызванное из Construct2'
```

Comment: Есть несколько НО: у вас для каждого экземпляра создаются своим методы, потому что записаны они не в прототипе + в вашем случае нельзя унаследовать приватные св-ва ( потому что они в замыкании )

Comment: лучше использовать https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class там уже и приватные св-ва подъезжают ( под капотом все те же прототипы )

Comment: @ThisMan точно, `prototype` забыл указать! Про классы из es6 знаю, но хочется на базовом уровне разобраться пока с этим.
В остальном, есть нарекания по коду?

Comment: > базовом уровне разобраться пока с этим
Классы это тоже базовый уровень, так что можете начинать с них

Comment: Непонятно насколько вы разобрались, т.к. тут не используются собственно прототипы

Comment: @AlexeyTen - обновил код в вопросе, посмотрите пожалуйста...

Comment: Теперь у вас сплошной прототип, но приватность это исключительно договорённость. Технически ничего не мешает кому угодно вызвать «приватный» метод и посмотреть в «приватное» свойство

Comment: @AlexeyTen `Теперь у вас сплошной прототип` - так я все правильно понял и написал код, или что то не так? `это исключительно договорённость` - т.е. в отличие от функционального стиля, здесь все на "честном слове"?

Comment: В целом правильно. Просто нужно принять, что в JS (пока) нет приватных свойств и методов.

Comment: @AlexeyTen `В целом правильно` - а что вы бы изменили? Можете оставить как "ответ" на вопрос, а я его выберу как "решение". Просто хочется все до мелочей понимать...

Comment: Ну ещё надо посмотреть и понять как делается наследование. И вообще прочитать https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes

Comment: @AlexeyTen понял, спасибо! Щас поправлю код

Comment: @AlexeyTen сделал наследование, вроде все работает